# Why are notifications so low?

Tags: notify-osd

Whenever notifications show up, they are much lower than I would expect. In most screenshots I see, they are directly under the top panel, but for me, there's a large gap:

[image]

Is there any way to change the position?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can customize their placement and appearance: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/customize-the-ubuntu-notification-bubbles/

Answer (score 16):

This was a change in Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic).

The space above is left intentionally blank because it is for "confirmation" bubbles: for instance volume, screen brightness, etc... (often controlled on keyboards buttons on using laptop buttons).

"Notification" bubbles appear in this space slightly further down.

Not everyone likes this, but this is the way the powers that be want it...

[image: Example of image with both confirmation and notification bubbles]

Comment: Interesting. I never use those buttons, so I didn't notice that, but I'm definitely in the group that doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I think that's the default from Maverick onwards - they were much higher in Lucid, but it were moved lower so that the first notification didn't obscure the typical place where window controls land.

No, as far as I know, there's no way to modify the placement or positioning of the notifications.

[Edit : Of course, Maverick isn't out yet - are you running one of the Betas or is this Lucid you're talking about? My Lucid build has notifications higher than your screenshot, just under the top panel.]

Comment: I'm running Lucid.

Comment: There are ways to edit the position and style of the notifications, as @DoR mentioned.

Comment: @aperson: I should point out that to edit the position and style, you apparently need a modified version of notify-osd. The PPA in the first step of @DoR's solution has the modified version.

Comment: I've been running that modified version since it's been available ;)