# How to install NotifyOSD-Config?

Tags: 11.10, notify-osd

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and I tried to install NotifyOSD-Config to no avail using the following code from this thread:
[How do I change how long notifications are displayed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50/how-do-i-change-how-long-notifications-are-displayed)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leolik/leolik
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:amandeepgrewal/notifyosdconfig
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig
```

But it doesn't appear in the accessories folder, and the last message I get using

```
sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig
```

is:

> E: Unable to locate package notifyosdconfig

I want to change the time of the bubble notification because it displays too long and change where it appears. Thank you in advance.

I also tried this code from this thread: [Why are notifications so low?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3326/why-are-notifications-so-low)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leolik/leolik
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:amandeepgrewal/notifyosdconfig
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig
```

It didn't work either.

Any suggestions on how to make NotifyOSD-Config work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ppa:amandeepgrewal/notifyosdconfig` hasn't been updated in a while and does not include packages for Ubuntu 11.04 or 11.10.

You can install `notifyosdconfig` from the main WebUpd8 PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig
```

It looks like you've been using an old guide. Use [this guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/configurable-notifyosd-bubbles-for.html) for configuring the patched NotifyOSD in Ubuntu Oneiric 11.10.

Comment: The `notifyosdconfig` package is no longer available for Ubuntu 15.04 and up in the webupd8 PPA. Checked according to [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/43583) with: `awk '$1 == "Package:" { print $2 }' /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_nilarimogard_webupd8_ubuntu_dists_wily_main_binary-i386_Packages`